# Solve nonlinear equation

Tags: equation-solving

Please help me to solve the following nonlinear equation, such that I used ''FindRoot"
but no result

the equation is
`` -10.499999997354678` (-0.006630671819814823+ x^3 +x^2(1.1599999999940591- 0.7999999999851477 Sqrt[1 + x]))-(-0.7(-0.1233952365163843+x) + 3.4999999989155866` (-0.13078703184428012` + x Sqrt[1 + x])) == 0 ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `NSolve` instead. In Version 12.2 it gives

```
ClearAll[x];
eq = -10.499999997354678 (-0.006630671819814823 + x^3 + 
       x^2 (1.1599999999940591 - 
          0.7999999999851477 Sqrt[
            1 + x])) - (-0.7 (-0.1233952365163843 + x) + 
      3.4999999989155866 (-0.13078703184428012` + x Sqrt[1 + x])) == 0;
NSolve[eq, x]
```

This solution

```
{{x -> -0.962771}, {x -> -0.510822 - 0.680662 I}, {x -> -0.510822 + 
    0.680662 I}, {x -> 0.123395}}
```

If you want in Reals, you could do

```
NSolve[eq, x, Reals]
```

which gives

```
{{x -> -0.962771}, {x -> 0.123395}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = -10.499999997354678 (-0.006630671819814823 + x^3 + 
      x^2 (1.1599999999940591 - 
         0.7999999999851477 Sqrt[
           1 + x])) - (-0.7 (-0.1233952365163843 + x) + 
     3.4999999989155866 (-0.13078703184428012` + x Sqrt[1 + x]));

FunctionDomain[f[x], x]

(* x >= -1 *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
NSolve[{f[x] == 0, -1 < x < 1}, x]

(* {{x -> -0.962771}, {x -> 0.123395}} *)

Solve[{f[x] == 0, -1 < x < 1}, x] // Quiet

(* {{x -> -0.962771}, {x -> 0.123395}} *)

FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {-1, .5}

(* {{x -> -0.962771}, {x -> 0.123395}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much dears. Thanks for all your Help